# Android Bypass 3G/4G Firewall with SSH Tunneling via JSch

Tags: java, android, ssh, jsch, ssh-tunnel

i am trying to connect to the internet from browser with mobile data and get free high speed 3G/4G internet connection in order to avoid high internet charges on plans by internet service providers from my android. To achieve this i implemented an ssh tunnel to bypass service provider firewall and forward the connection to a proxy. Thus i will configure the browser with the above proxy to surf to the internet. Do am i Right?. if yes how to create a local proxy to forward the ssh tunnel (cant forward to localhost due to it is not wifi connection).  can anyone give me some directions and point to me  the right way.

```
 int rport=3451;
        String lhost="hostport";
        int lport=2231;
        String user="user";
        String password = "password";

        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();

            String host = null;
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user,host, 22);


            session.setPassword(password);

            session.connect();
            session.setPortForwardingR(rport, lhost, lport);

            System.out.println(host + ":" + rport + " -> " + lhost + ":" + lport);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```